# Copy and paste content from a textbox to a worksheet cell range?

Tags: vba, excel, textbox

I'm working on a VBA project to automate the Excel tool for a service desk queries tracker. I want, once the command button is clicked, to copy the content from a textbox to another worksheet row. If I repeat the task, the textbox content should be saved in the next empty cell of the same row.

I used this macro:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    TextBox1.Text = ""
    TextBox1.Copy
    'TextBox2.Copy
    'TextBox3.Copy
    Range("A2").Select
    Do
        If IsEmpty(ActiveCell) = False Then
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        End If
    Loop Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell) = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You really only need one line of code in your sub:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Range("A2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = TextBox1.Text
End Sub
```

Even though you don't say so, it looks like you want the textbox to be cleared as well. If so, then add `TextBox1.Text = ""` one line before `End Sub`.