# Listening for mouse (drag-and-drop) events in MS Excel

Tags: events, vba, excel, drag-and-drop

Is there a way to recognize a drag and drop event on a MS Excel sheet? What I am looking for is to be able to listen to the event when you drag and drop a file (say from desktop) onto a cell in a MS Excel sheet (and have the file's name inserted into the cell).

Can this be achieved at all with Excel Macros?.

Comment: You can use the "BeforeDragOver" event on a UserForm object to register the drag and drop action, but the only data that it can interpret is text which is stored on the clipboard. I'm not sure if there is a solution for this one...

Comment: Triggering a DragDrop event as you have described requires this Event to be available at the Workbook level, which is not the case. DragDrop event is only available as part of a Form, not a Workbook, or worksheet.

Comment: I actually see some resources out there that make me think this *is* possible, but I am having trouble myself getting any of it to work. Have you tried anything yourself? [Link from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg264583.aspx) is one example. Again, I can't quite get it to work myself, but this looks very promising.

Comment: @Gaffi did you have any success with this? It seams that this drag-and-drop functionality is for objects (controls) that are added to the sheet. But it is not available for Excel `Range`, `Cell` or `Worksheet` objects themselves? So, the answer to OP answer would be - no, there is no way to recognize drag-and-drop event for MS Excel `Worksheet`, I guess

Comment: @Prokurors No, I did not get a solution to this myself.

Answer (score 1):

I myself was unsure how to perform the task - however, it appears someone has already attempted to tackle the issue. I pulled this code from [vbadud.blogspot](http://vbadud.blogspot.com/2007/05/drag-drop-files-to-text-box.html):

```
' Place file on textbox to display filename.
Private Sub TextBox1_OLEDragDrop(Data As DataObject, Effect As Long, Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)

' Declare variable(s).
Dim eventvar1 As Integer '* Files Counter

' If an error occurs, go to the Error Handler.
On Error GoTo Error_Handle1
'Drag N' Drop Event Handler
If Data.GetFormat(vbCFFiles) = True Then
eventvar1 = Data.Files.Count
    If eventvar1 = 1 Then
        If InStr(1, LCase$(Data.Files(eventvar1)), ".xls") Then
            txtExcel.Text = Data.Files(eventvar1)
        End If
    End If
End If

   ' Error Handler
    Error_Handle1:
        If Err <> 0 Then
            Debug.Assert Err = 0
            Err.Clear
        End If
    End Sub
```

The code will post the name of the file if it is put into the textbox. You can use a method, function or even a separate subroutine to make use of the text which has been placed into the textbox.

For instance, examining an [SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9461260/copy-and-paste-content-from-a-textbox-to-a-worksheet-cell-range) on copying text from a textbox to a cell, you can use this code to input the text into a range on your excel sheet:

```
Range("A2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = TextBox1.Text
```

From there, its a matter of either tying the subroutines to another macro for one form of automation or another, dragging and dropping as you see fit, or whatever makes sense for you.

Let me know if that helps,

~JOL

Comment: Hi, this code seams to be about dragging some stuff on-to controls, not the sheet itself. Might be helpful, but seams to be something different than what OP was asking for...